# ...wound sky down to desert

Tags: meaning-in-context

"Well out of the city, out where the first of a crop of white windmills, lazily turning, **wound sky down to desert**, Driver sailed without warning onto an exit ramp and into a one-eighty." [*Drive*, James Sallis]

In the sentence above, is the bolded phrase talking about the turning direction of the windmills, or about something different?

Comment: This is a case of literary interpretation and suited for writersSE.

Comment: Ilhan, please add a reference and quote correctly when quoting from a book.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a vivid phrase for the windmill sails turning in the sky, like somebody winding a thread (or a hose) onto a reel; they must be pulling the sky down to the desert because they are the only two things in sight.

Comment: Would your answer be any different if the case were to belong in another language?

Comment: +1 because this gets at the sense of what is going on in the description. But note that the passage mentions at least four things that are in view.